# awk combine sequence with substring key

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two files for combining with tab delimited file.
That two files key might be different only for "Reads" number.

I want to compare that two files and combined based on substring key and match.

Forexample,

```
File1 Key : "Cluster0_Reads255" 
File2 Key : "Cluster0_Reads50"
This case is same because "Cluster0_Reads" is identical.
```

This case I want to combine that two column with File1 Key name.
Please check below example case.

File 1.

```
       A                B             
Cluster0_Reads255      500
Cluster1_Reads253      300
Cluster2_Reads100      200
Cluster3_Reads100      350
```

File 2.

```
        A               C          
Cluster0_Reads50       GE
Cluster1_Reads200      GA
Cluster2_Reads100      GA
```

Result.

```
       A                B       C            
Cluster0_Reads255      500     GE
Cluster1_Reads253      300     GA
Cluster2_Reads100      200     GA
Cluster3_Reads100      350     -
```

I made one awk with exact match find and combine like below,

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
{key = $1}
FNR == NR {result[key] = $0; next;}
(key in result) { updated[key]=1 ; for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"    # if using GNU awk
    for (key in result) {
            if(!(key in updated)) result[key] = result[key] FS "-"
            if(!(length(key)==0)) print result[key]
    }
}
' File1 File2 > File3
```

Is there any way to combine after substring?

Thank you.

Comment: your sample input seems to be sorted in first column (Cluster 0,1,2,3).. if that is true, you could do something like `paste t1 <(awk '{print $2}' t2) | perl -pe 's/^(\S+[ \t]+){2}$/$&-/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below kinda dirty `awk` script does the job, but i'm sure you would find a better one ere.

```
awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" '
NR==FNR{f1=$1;sub(/[0-9]*$/,"",f1);file1info[f1]=$0;next}
       {sub(/[0-9]*$/,"",$1);file2info[$1]=$2}
    END{
        for(i in file1info){
        print file1info[i],(i in file2info)?file2info[i]:"-";
        }
       }' File1 File2 | expand -t 20 | sort -nk1
```

**Output**

```
A                   B                   C          
Cluster0_Reads255   500                 GE
Cluster1_Reads253   300                 GA
Cluster2_Reads100   200                 GA
Cluster3_Reads100   350                 -
```

**Edit**

Finally managed to get a smaller faster one. The trick was reversing the files considering that file2's clusters always form a subset of file1's.

```
awk -v FS="\t" -v OFS="\t" '
NR==FNR{sub(/[0-9]*$/,"",$1);file2info[$1]=$2;next}
       {f1=$1;sub(/[0-9]*$/,"",f1);print $0,(f1 in file2info)?file2info[f1]:"-"}
       ' File2 File1   | expand -t 20 |sort -nk1
```

**Output**

```
A                   B                   C          
Cluster0_Reads255   500                 GE
Cluster1_Reads253   300                 GA
Cluster2_Reads100   200                 GA
Cluster3_Reads100   350                 -
```

Comment: Solution 2 is particularly nice :) +1

Comment: @clear.choi : I doubted that, but thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu AWK:

```
$ cat > do.awk
FNR==NR {
    a[gensub(/[0-9]+$/,"","g",$1)]=$0         # remove nums from end of index
    next 
} 
(i=gensub(/[0-9]+$/,"","g",$1)) && (i in a) { # if match in a
    sub(/\t/,OFS $2 OFS,a[i])                 # change order
    $0=a[i]
} 1                                           # print
$ awk -v OFS="\t" file2 file1
A       B       C
Cluster0_Reads50        500     GE
Cluster1_Reads200       300     GA
Cluster2_Reads100       200     GA
Cluster3_Reads100       350
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{ key=$1; sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",key) }
NR==FNR { map[key]=$2; next }
{ print $0, (key in map ? map[key] : "-") }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
A       B       C
Cluster0_Reads255       500     GE
Cluster1_Reads253       300     GA
Cluster2_Reads100       200     GA
Cluster3_Reads100       350     -

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1 | column -s$'\t' -t
A                  B    C
Cluster0_Reads255  500  GE
Cluster1_Reads253  300  GA
Cluster2_Reads100  200  GA
Cluster3_Reads100  350  -
```